# Determine $corr(X + Y, X − Y )$

Tags: probability

Let $X, Y$ be real random variables.

We know about the standard deviations and the correlations of them that
$$σ_{Y} = 2σ_{X}$$
and 
$$\text{corr}(X, Y ) = −\frac{3}{4}.$$
The task is to determine
$$\text{corr}(X + Y, X − Y ).$$

---

I know that 
the definition of the correlation of $X-Y$ and $X+Y$ is
$$\frac{E[(X-Y-E[X-Y])(X+Y-E[X+Y])]}{\sigma_{X-Y}\sigma_{X+Y}},$$
where
$$\sigma_{X-Y}^2=E[(X-Y-(E[X]-E[Y]))^2]=E[(X-Y)^2]-E^2[X-Y]$$
and
$$\sigma_{X+Y}^2=E[(X+Y-(E[X]+E[Y]))^2]=E[(X+Y)^2]-E^2[X+Y].$$
and
$$\sigma^2_{X}=E[(X-E[X])^2]=E[X^2]-E^2[X]$$
and
$$\sigma^2_{X}=E[(Y-E[Y])^2]=E[Y^2]-E^2[Y].$$
Based on all this I was not able to see the relationship between the givens and the definitions. Whatever I did resulted in a mess. I am new to this and I am in need of your help. Please guide me out of this jungle.

Answer (score 1):

$$cov((X-Y)(X+Y))=E[(X-Y-(E[X]-E[Y]))(X+Y-(E[X]+E[Y]))]=$$
$$=E\left[X^2\right]+E[XY]-E^2[X]-E[X]E[Y]-$$
$$-E[XY]-E\left[Y^2\right]+E[X]E[Y]+E^2[Y]-$$
$$-E^2[X]-E[X][Y]+E^2[X]+E[X]E[Y]$$
$$+E[X]E[Y]+E^2[Y]-E[X]E[Y]-E^2[Y]=$$
$$=E\left[X^2\right]-E^2[X]-\left(E\left[Y^2\right]-E^2[Y]\right)=$$
$$=\sigma_X^2-\sigma^2_Y=-3\sigma_X^2$$

---

$$corr(X,Y)=\frac{cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}=\frac{E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]}{2\sigma_X^2}=-\frac{3}{4}$$,
$$\sigma_{X-Y}^2=5\sigma_X^2-2(E[XY]-E[X]E[Y])=8\sigma_X^2,$$
$$\sigma_{X+Y}^2=5\sigma_X^2+2(E[XY]-E[X]E[Y])=2\sigma_X^2,$$
$$\sigma_{X-Y}\sigma_{X+Y}=4\sigma_X^2$$

---

$$corr(X-Y,X+Y)=\frac{cov(X-Y)(X+Y)}{\sigma_{X-Y}\sigma_{X+Y}}=-\frac{3}{4}=corr(X,Y).$$

Comment: how to calculate $σ^{2}_{X-Y}} $

Comment: @KrzysztofSzymski, my brother (HUN and POL are bratinki!), I edited your original post.  I would like you to take a look at my edits to see how to present a question here. I've done this for you because I do believe that this site is a great resource of knowledge and expert help. First of all, please, learn how to use MathJax. The people around (those who may help you) don't like lazy questions. (BTW: I answered your question in my edits.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: find

- $var(X)$
- $var(Y)$
- $cov(X,Y)$
- $cov(X+Y,X-Y)$
- $var(X+Y)$
- $var(X-Y)$
- $corr(X+Y,X-Y)$